# option for hot sunroom floor

Tags: floor, laminate-floor, vinyl, sunroom

i have a  sunroom, summer time sunroom can be hot over>100 F degree, laminate or vinyl planks which one is better and can tolerated hot weather?

Comment: Have you looked at the manufacturer's spec sheets for the products you're interested in? They will usually give environmental constraints like min/max temperature. Also, since you specify "better" _and_ tolerate hot weather, what does "better" mean? Be very specific as to what you're looking for, or this will likely get closed because an unspecified "better" is merely opinion.

Comment: @FreeMan I’d upvote this if it was an answer. Too often I see answers on this site cite examples based on their experiences. All manufacturers test their products and then include recommendations in their product specifications. Always follow the manufacturers recommendations.

Comment: I would consider ceramic tile .

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you review the manufacturer's specifications for the products you're interested in installing. Nobody will know the products better or have tested them in more conditions that the manufacturer. They'll be able to tell you the environmental constraints, like minimum and maximum temperatures and water resistance.

If you can't find these items listed on the spec sheets, use the "contact us" link that's bound to be somewhere on their web-site to send them a question to ask specifically.

As to which one is better - that's a personal opinion, and we can't answer that for you, especially since you haven't defined what criteria you're interested in measuring to determining "better".

Comment: I agree........